# Synapse Serverless SQL parallel queries performance killer?

Tags: sql-server, serverless, azure-synapse, microsoft-fabric

We have moved our EDW to Synapse Serverless SQL.

The data is in a delta lake, which is accessed by views, to make use of the partitioning on the tables.

However we are experiencing "blocking" behavior.
Typically what happens is that a user starts a long running query, any following query then seems to "hang"

It might literally be a
select 1 n
query, which will hang for perhaps 2 minute before returning the value.

So it seems like there is some limit on ressources on serverless sql not related to the underlying storage account, since we experience it even if the source files are on separate storage accounts.

Strangely I cannot see any documentation as to how to avoid this issue. This means we are severely hampered in high traffic hours where the users will experience that all queries take a long time, no matter the size.

Is this ressource limitation documented anywhere, and are there any solutions, besides switching to dedicated pool, with the increased overhead associated with that?

Comment: Have you checked this page? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/synapse-analytics/dedicated-sql/troubleshoot-dsql-perf-slow-query

Comment: You may need to request a Quota increase. The default value is very low, and to my knowledge the setting is not exposed anywhere. You can request an increase via a Support Ticket.

Comment: @siggemannen Thank you - yes, however that's for dedicated pools. and we do not have the same option in regards to serverless pools